# reduce method in javascript gets undefined

Tags: javascript, function, methods, reduce

How do I use the reduce method in solving this problem? I keep getting undefined. I am trying to only print out the numbers that are bigger while going through the loop. so for example [ 1,4,2,9,1,12] will give me the printout of 1,4,9,12-  here is what I got... and I keep getting undefined for the accumulator????

**

```
function main(array){
    let myNum;
    let answer=[];
    outPut = array.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
        const num = accumulator;
        myNum= num > element? answer.push(num): 
                   answer.push(element);
    }, 0);
    console.log(outPut);
}**
    
    main([20, 3, 22, 15, 6, 1]);
```

Comment: You need to return the accumulation.

Comment: The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

Comment: function main(arr) {
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (acc <= cur) {
            console.log(cur)
            acc = cur
        }
        return acc
    }, 0)
}

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the accumulator in `reduce()`.

A simpler version is to check the index is zero or value is greater than previous in the accumulator to determine whether to add current value or not

```js
const data = [ 1,4,2,9,1,2,12];

const res = data.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    return (!i || c > a[a.length-1]) ? a.concat(c) : a; 
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because the `reduce()` works with callback which return nunber. You are not returning anything.

But the main issue is the fact you are pushing items into `answer`. But then you are trying to log `outPut`, which is not initialized and the only value it could have is from wrongly used `reduce()`.

Try this:

```js
function main(array){
    let myNum;
    let answer=[];
    array.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
        const num = accumulator;
        let biggerOne;
        if(num > element) {
            biggerOne = num;
        } else {
            biggerOne = element;
        }
        answer.push(biggerOne);
        return biggerOne;
    }, 0);
    console.log(answer);
}**
    
    main([20, 3, 22, 15, 6, 1]);
```

Comment: The callback for `reduce()` should return the new `acc` value... To be used in the next iteration or the result. Not a boolean.

Comment: Yeah, I lightly missed the point. I edited the code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want `[1,4,2,9,1,12]` to return `[1,4,9,12]`, array.reduce isn't the way to go.

Try

```js
function sortArray(array) {
    const sortedArray = array
                        .sort((a, b) => a - b) //sort by ascending
                        .filter((e, index) => array.indexOf(e) == index) //remove duplicates
    console.log(sortedArray);
}
```